# add a field to each record that shows when and how many people visited it?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table and in that is individual records. What I'd like to do is be able to have a field for each record that shows how many people have visited each record.

For example:

> Jame's Record - Visited 10 times
>
> Joe's Record - Visited 3 times

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Yes. I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: yes it is; just add an int column and update it +1 on each execution of your php script

Comment: Cheers Jamie haha. So just to clarify Tularis I execute the +1 using PHP? (sorry relatively new to PHP so may appear a stupid question!) Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

Add a field in user row named view_count and on every view update this field with +1 using

`UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE [...]`

Solution 2:

Create a lable view_log

Fields `id,table,row_id`

And on every view function insert a new row into this table with table and row id.

And when u wana get count just run

`Select count(I'd) from view_log where table = 'users' and row_I'd =  'x'`

Then u will get counts :)

If you want to monitor update,insert, delete then u can use `mysql` trigger to do it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have tried the first one and can't seem to get it to work with in my script. I'm new to mysql and PHP so still learning lol. The below is where I have tried to insert it:
`$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM website, online JOIN search_1 ON search_1.id_search_1 = online.id JOIN marketing ON marketing.business_id = online.id UPDATE online SET view_count = view_count + 1 WHERE wibble_a6 = '".$wibble_a6."'");`

Comment: Oh now, u need to split our SQL commands ,  run update command in another mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, You can simply do this using session.Make a view field in table that record the no of times record has been viewed.
Make session for new user's ,Whenever new user is on that user's record page increment that view field by 1 and if same user is  visiting that record destroy the session.

Comment: Sessions are not persistent across users.

Comment: if user keeps on refreshing page then view will keep on incrementing,In this case how you will handle?

Comment: Probably using user IP. Stored in db to I'd unique visitors and actions